# Group Theory and Lagrange's Theorem: coprime subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be finite groups, and let $K≤G_1 \times G_2$. Let $H_1 = \{ g \in G_1 : (g,e) \in K\}$ and $H_2 = \{g \in G_2 : (e,g) \in K\}$ and suppose $|G_1|$ and $|G_2|$ are coprime. Then show that $H_1 \times H_2 = K$. Show that if $|G_1|$ and $|G_2|$ are not coprime then this does not have to be the case.

**My working:**
I have proved that $H_1 ≤ G_1$, $H_2 ≤ G_2$ and $H_1 \times H_2 ≤ K$. And since $|G_1|, |G_2|$ are coprime, we must have $|H_1|, |H_2|$ are also coprime. Then given that $|G_1 \times G_2|$ = $|G_1||G_2|$, I am trying to use Bézout's Lemma or some similar thing to show that $H_1 \times H_2 = K$.

As for the second part, I have no idea.

Comment: [possible dup](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764939/g-1-and-g-2-are-coprime-show-that-k-h-1-times-h-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, just consider two groups $G_{1}, G_{2}$ of order $2$, say, and let $K$ be the diagonal subgroup.

For the first part, you are right in wanting to use Bezout. Suppose the order of $G_{i}$ is $n_{i}$, and find suitable $a_{i}$ such that
$$
a_{1} n_{1} + a_{2} n_{2} = 1.
$$
Take any $(h, k) \in K$, and note that
$$
(h, k)^{a_{1} n_{1}} = (e, k^{a_{1} n_{1}}), \text{so that } k^{a_{1} n_{1}}\in H_{2},
\qquad
(h, k)^{a_{2} n_{2}} = (h^{a_{2} n_{2}}, e), \text{so that } h^{a_{2} n_{2}} \in H_{1}.
$$
Now
$$
(h, k) = (h, k)^{1} =
(h, k)^{a_{1} n_{1} + a_{2} n_{2}}
=
(e, k^{a_{1} n_{1}}) \cdot (h^{a_{2} n_{2}}, e)
=
(h^{a_{2} n_{2}}, k^{a_{1} n_{1}}) \in H_{1} \times H_{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating the problem.

$H_1 \times H_2 \subset K$ is easy.

For the other implication, let $|H_1|=m$ and $|H_2|=n$.

You know that 
$$
1=nk+ml
$$

Now, if $x \in K$ prove that 
$$x^{nk}=(e,y) \,;\, y \in H_2$$
$$x^{ml}=(z,e) \,;\, z \in H_1$$
and deduce from here that
$$x=(z, y)$$