# Subgroups of product of two finite groups with coprime order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to explain the following proposition (if true).

> Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be finite groups with coprime orders and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G_1 \times G_2$. Then there exists subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ of $G_1$ and $G_2$, respectively, so that $H = H_1 \times H_2$.

Of course, if familiar, it can be handled by the the Gourat's lemma. Note that it suffices to prove that 'if the images of $H$ under the natural projections are $G_1$ and $G_2$, then $H=G_1 \times G_2$'. By the lemma the quotients of $G_j$ by the kernels are isomorphic to each other and hence, should be trivial because of the coprime orders. This implies that $H = G_1 \times G_2$.

I want to explain the proposition to the students of undergraduate sophomore level. Can you help to develop a suitable explanation or proof of the proposition? (By the way, they are familiar with Sylow blah, I guess)

PS: Sadly(?) I just found the following question. This post may be treated as duplicate.

[$ |G_1 |$ and $|G_2 | $ are coprime. Show that $K = H_1 \times H_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764939/g-1-and-g-2-are-coprime-show-that-k-h-1-times-h-2?rq=1)

Comment: What DO the students know?

Comment: I can thik of a proof using the nine-lemma, but I am not sure it is that enlightening.

Comment: @Igor More specifically they are usually taught by Freleigh's algebra textbook.

Comment: Well, the proof by nine-lemma is quite easy (and the proof OF the nine-lemma is easy). The downside is that it is kind of tedious. The upside is that this is the RIGHT proof - going into Sylow is obviously gross overkill.

Comment: @IgorRivin I agree and moreover I feel like using nine-lemma would be illuminating. However, they are completely unfamiliar with homological ideas. Anyway, thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a completely elementary proof, which does not use nine-lemma, Goursat's lemma or Sylow theorems.

Let $H_1$ the set of elements $h_1\in G_1$ such that $H$ contains an element of the form $(h_1,g_2)$ for some $g_2\in G_2$, and similarly, let $H_2$ the set of elements $h_2\in G_2$ such that $H$ contains an element of the form $(g_1,h_2)$ for some $g_1\in G_1$.

Clearly, $H_i$ is a subgroup of $G_i$ and $H\subset H_1\times H_2$.

Let us prove the reverse inclusion. Let $(h_1,h_2)\in H_1\times H_2$.

By definition, $(h_1,g_2)\in H$ and $(g_1,h_2)\in H$ for some $g_i\in G_i$.

Let $m_i$ the order of $g_i$. Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G_1\times G_2$, we get that $(h_1^{am_2},1), (1,h_2^{bm_1})\in H$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Since $m_2$ divides the order of $G_2$, it is coprime to the order of $G_1$, hence to the order of $h_1$. Hence $uo(h_1)+vm_2=1$ for some $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Thus $h_1^{vm_2}=h_1$ , so taking $a=v$ above yields $(h_1,1)\in H$. Similarly, $(1,h_2)\in H$, and finally $(h_1,h_2)\in H$, that is $H_1\times H_2\subset H$. a

Consequently, $H=H_1\times H_2$.